# Deprecated getTabHost() in HelloTabWidget tutorial

Tags: android

I was doing the HelloTabWidget tutorial 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html 
and getting errors on the *"TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();"* statement. I thumbed threw the stackOverflow notes and it seems a few people were having the same problem, and a few received responses along the lines of **"Note: Tabactivitity deprecated in latest versions, consider learning Fragments"** and discovered I can use **... the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.** although I haven't quiet figured out how to do this.

My question is - If the function is deprecated, and causing newbies problems, shouldn't the tutorials be updates to use the new functions? Is their a polite/politically correct way to let the people in charge of the tutorials know that an update may be in order? Or maybe new tutorials exist, and I'm just looking at an old URL?

Comment: *shouldn't the tutorials be updates to use the new functions?* not necessary. That tutorial shows how to use the `TabActivity` in an android app and this hasn't changed. The deprecation means that you should look at other ways to do what you curently are trying to do with the `TabActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't the tutorials be updates to use the new functions

Who exactly are you asking this to? Us? Why would we know why google hasn't updated their docs/tutorials.

> is their a polite/politically correct way to let the people in charge
>   of the tutorials know that an update may be in order?

I'm very sure that they know. They probably have more important things to do. There are TONS of tutorials around the internet. They don't need to update all their tutorials.

> Or maybe new tutorials exist, and I'm just looking at an old URL?

Search google. There's TONS of blogs that will give you lots of examples. Including here at stack overflow.